# Filtering out OLED electrical noise

Tags: power-supply, adc, filter, signal, emi-filtering

I have an [OLED display](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssd1306%200.96%20oled) and a high gain op-amp on the same circuit. When OLED is powered on and displaying something, it creates a electrical noise on the output of the opamp. Here is what I tried:

- Opamp and OLED power lines are decoupled with closely-positioned 100nf ceramic caps.
- The display is mounted directly behind of the said opamp. To determine if noise is not caused by radiated EMI by the display itself, I connected the display away from the PCB by running a wire. No change.
- Added an LC filter to op-amp supply (ferrite bead and 100n+10u after). No change.
- If I supply the OLED with a seperate power supply, the problem goes away (output looks same as if OLED disconnected).

Here is a scope capture. Please ignore the rising/falling edges.

[image: scope capture]

The OLED driver internally generates ~9V for driving the display. It uses a capacitance multiplier for that and probably that's my problem.

Any help/idea on filtering this supply noise would be appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

- Current draw of the OLED: 10mA@5V
- What is opamp doing: It is [MCP601](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21314g.pdf) that I'm using as a thermocouple frontend. Output goes to an ADC (no load).
- Other noise sources: Circuit is supplied with (clean) 12V, goes through on-board 5V linear regulator (with its input and output caps). Everything (OLED, op-amp and MCU) is on the same supply.
- Routing: Two layer PCB with ground pour on each layer. I did not do star grounding though.
- Decoupling on OLED: I modded the OLED board with its supply passes through a ferrite+100n, no change.
- Ferrite bead: I tried what I have on hand, [BLM21PG331SN1D](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Electronics/BLM21PG331SN1D?qs=bLvI9hvPQQYsUnnUi%2Fpnsg==) and [FBMJ2125HS250NT](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Taiyo-Yuden/FBMJ2125HS250NT?qs=I6KAKw0tg2w%2F7qNkMvc%2FCQ==).

Comment: Show the entire schematic. Do you have any switchers in the project? If you have a PCB layout show that also. What does your ground look like?

Comment: also, how much current does your OLED display draw? It'd probably be better to decouple the source of noise than just the sensitive opamp. How much does the opamp draw? Can you specify which ferrite bead you used?

Comment: Oh, and by the way: what are the frequencies of the signals the Opamp is *supposed* to deal with?

Comment: because of ESR bypass caps have frequency ranges where they're most effective.  The noise looks high enough in frequency that I'd add 1 nF caps in parallel with the 100nF bypass caps.

Comment: Thank you for the input, for formatting purposes I made an edit to question; please find the answers at "Edit 1" section.

Comment: I'd also try an experiment where the probe tip touches ground and see how much noise is picked up by the scope without the circuit at all – just from the ground loop of the probe.

Comment: @scorpdaddy Tried with additional 1n (both on OLED and opamp), no change. BTW I made these measurements with an ground spring on the probe to avoid making and antenna with probe ground lead.

Comment: Would it be possible to give the OLED its own linear regulator (12V to 5V) if needed preceeded by a pi filter instead of only a input cap?

Comment: put 10 (ten) ohm resistors in the supply pins to opamp. Or even 100 ohm. And you have a Ground plane, right? so Efields are intercepted.

Comment: @sabbath how fast is the thermocouple? I.e. in what time do you expect change?

Comment: Ohhh and I presume you forgot a filter between opamp and ADC?

Comment: -Huisman This is the last resort but even if I do that I'm afraid that this yet-unfilterable noise will seep through that second linear regulator - but I'll try.
-analogsystemsrf I'll try and report. 
-MarcusMüller I'm reading it 100 times per second and running that through a software low-pass filter. There is a 150ohm resistor between op-amp output and ADC but no real filtering. But why a filter is needed there? I thought that my problem is a supply noise/filtering issue.

Comment: Well, you don't really care about where the noise comes from, do you? It's only as relevant as it is to your signal. I'd agree, low-pass filtering digitally is what I'd recommend, but you need to make sure that no noise aliases down into the low-pass band that you need to keep; so, add an analog anti-aliasing RC filter between ADC and opamp. basically, just an analog filter that cuts off somewhere between your maximum signal frequency and half your ADC rate.

Answer (score 1):

A large (330uF) capacitor between VDD,VSS is definitly worth doing but you should also investigate tweaking your OLED init code.  Many OLED's have lots of config options to do with voltages and frequencies that can really make a difference to the amount of electrical noise they make by reducing their overall current draw but also by altering the "pattern" of said current draw.

I had the same problem as you with SSD1327 OLED from waveshare. The default configs work great but produced a significant amount of noise in my audio output.  The main turned out to be the refresh rate that was well into the audible range at around 120Hz and much higher than actually necessary.  A bit of tweaking to the internal oscillator config reduced the frame rate to a much lower value leading to less noise in the audible range. Futher tweaking to drive voltages reduced the scale of that noise so much that is almost unnoticable in my application.

I wrote more about it over on the [EEVblog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/oled-audible-noise/msg2752588/#msg2752588)